# How to be Sure that page downloaded is complete by python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I am downloading a JSON based huge page, most of the time it is downloaded successfully but sometimes, its downloading partially. How can I sure that download completed.

My example code is as follows:

```
mac_sonuclari_url = "http://mservice.fanatik.com.tr/LeagueStage?TournamentID={}&includeFixture=1"
with urllib.request.urlopen(mac_sonuclari_url.format(1)) as url:
     try:
         data = json.loads(url.read().decode())    
     except Exception as err:
         logging.error("{}: Error Getting URL: {} with Error: {}".format(fna, mac_sonuclari_url.format(1), err))
```

unfortunately, I can't catch partial download by Try - Except. 
Then my code breaks as it doesn't catch all data needed.
Is there any way to understand that page loaded completely?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You could do a size check of the read string against the returned 'Content-Length' header? If all data has been retrieved, the two sizes should agree.

Comment: I will check it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, I added as you suggested, now I am following if it will help. I put also logging to see if it will fail because of size issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, I tested and seems that this is the only option, if header size doesn't much with the download size, i ask user to retry. you may post this as answer so i can accept. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[From the comments]*

You could do a size check of the read string against the returned 'Content-Length' header. If all data has been retrieved, the two sizes should agree.